# Use custom data types as Tokens in Parser

Tags: haskell, parser-combinators

I'm trying to write a Parser using Parser Combinators and using my own Tokens defined by a custom data type instead of using `languageDef` like in https://wiki.haskell.org/Parsing_a_simple_imperative_language

So far I've got a basic parser for testing parsers from here https://jakewheat.github.io/intro_to_parsing/#very-simple-expression-parsing

```
import Data.Char (isLetter, isDigit)
import Control.Monad
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.Char (digit)

regularParse :: Parser a -> String -> Either ParseError a
regularParse p = parse p ""

-- regularParse num "143"
num :: Parser Integer
num = do
    n <- many1 digit
    return (read n)

-- regularParse var "hello, world!"
var :: Parser String
var = do
    fc <- firstChar
    rest <- many nonFirstChar
    return (fc:rest)
  where
    firstChar = satisfy (\a -> isLetter a || a == '_')
    nonFirstChar = satisfy (\a -> isDigit a || isLetter a || a == '_')
```

In the first example from the wiki.haskell.org, the language and tokens are defined using `emptyDef` from `Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.Language`. This allows them to write the language like

```
languageDef =
    emptyDef { Token.commentStart    = "/*"
             , ...
             , Token.reservedNames   = [ "if"
                                       , "while"
                                       , ...

lexer = Token.makeTokenParser languageDef
reserved = Token.reserved lexer

whileStmt :: Parser Stmt
whileStmt =
  do reserved "while"
     cond <- bExpression
     reserved "do"
     stmt <- statement
     return $ While cond stmt
```

How could I do this if I wanted to write my own custom data types and use my own tokens such as

```
data Token = Zero
           | One [Char]
           | Two [Char] [Char]

token :: Parser Token
token = twoParser
     <|> oneParser
     <|> zeroParser

twoParser :: Parser Token
twoParser = do
  two <- tExpression
  a <- var
  b <- var
  return $ two a b

tExpression :: Parser Token
tExpression = do
  ...

var :: Parser String
var = do
    fc <- firstChar
    rest <- many nonFirstChar
    return (fc:rest)
  where
    firstChar = satisfy (\a -> isLetter a || a == '_')
    nonFirstChar = satisfy (\a -> isDigit a || isLetter a || a == '_')
```

I'm not sure if this is the correct way to approach this, and as the tExpression function relies on many things from the language definition. Thanks